# Option to change the Navigation is not available under Change the look pane on Team site

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, navigation, modern-team-site

I am observing some strange behavior with the Modern Teams Site. I want to shift the Navigation to Horizontal from verticle on the team site.

We can do this change from Change the look pane but surprisingly I don't see the Navigation option there.

[image]

However, on my dev tenant and on another tenant, I can see the option. I checked the web template and for all the sites it is the same "Group".

Can anyone help me here understand this behavior?

**Update on Site Creation:**

The site was created using Teams using the normal creation options. The Teams was linked to an existing O365 group which was created first to enable Outlook Groups and calendars as well. Nothing special, no tools or anything else.

Comment: Is this site created from SP UI or migrated using any tool? or converted classic team site to modern group site?

Comment: Whether this issue occurs to all site collections?

Comment: @EmilyDu-MSFT We are observing inconsistent behavior.

Comment: @GaneshSanap don't have that information yet

Comment: Any update for the issue?

Comment: @EmilyDu-MSFT added additional information on site creation in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally!!!!!!

If the **SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure** is enabled then the Site Navigation option is not available.

Disabled the above feature and then I can see the Navigation option under Change the look pane.